# Are Wallets "Forward" Compatible?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, cold-storage

So, I generated a "cold" wallet with a previous version of Moneromooo's generator a while back.

I checked balance and transactions at [xmr.llcoins.net](https://xmr.llcoins.net/), then stowed it.

Can I be assured that this wallet/seed will remain patent going forward or might there be some reason to create another wallet and transfer funds at some point?

Thank-you!

Answer (score 4):

Basically, as long as the wordlist or the format doesn't change, the wallets are forward compatible with respect to 25 word mnemonic seeds. Furthermore, I am certain that, even if the wordlist or format changes, the devs will make sure the old seeds are forward compatible. However, I don't expect either to change in the foreseeable future. There was a minor change in the beginning of 2015, because there was an issue with a few of the words.

Bear in mind that you are always able to restore from keys as well. That is, restore your wallet from the spendkey and viewkey. Therefore, I'd advise to note down these keys too, in addition to the 25 word mnemonic seed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I record the mnemonic phrase and all 3 keys for every one of my wallets, CLI-generated one's also, and store them in VeraCrypt containers.